# deployed <actionOverride> but action not overriden

Tags: metadata, button-overrides

I am overriding the edit button with a lightning component, in my sandbox it works fine. See the metadata:

[image]

when deploying I only deployed the section of metadata that I wanted to add, it looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>Edit</actionName>
        <content>Sales_Lex_OpportunityEdit</content>
        <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
        <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
        <type>LightningComponent</type>
    </actionOverrides>
</CustomObject>
```

I thought this was all you had to do, am I wrong ?

The deployement was successful but in that environment the edit button in lightning is not overriden:

[image]

Comment: You need to add the actual `Sales_Lex_OpportunityEdit` lightning component to the deployment if it doesn't already exist on the org you're deploying to

Comment: Thanks! It was deployed in the deployment before, then I forgot to add the metadata in that pr, so I this change seperately. Does that matter ?

Comment: Honestly it doesn't sound like it should matter, but it could be some internal check that SF does where it would need the lightning component to be sent (like to recompile it, etc).

Comment: Hm I'll try it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be `lightningcomponent` not `LightningComponent`